# Using mv command won't recognize * as wildcard

Tags: bash, shell, awk, mv

I have this script, and I know the awk command in it works, but when I want to save the output using the same name of the file it used to do the task using the `mv` command the `*` is not used as a wildcard but instead as a character and I end up with a file with a name like this:

> Algeria_BER_*_sites.txt

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in Algeria_BER 
do

 echo awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] RS $0}' \
     reduced_filt_MAF_b37_chr1_${i}_ldhat.txt_names ${i}_*_sites.txt > $$.tmp &&
   mv $$.tmp "${i}_*_sites.txt"

done
```

Comment: You can't use a pattern that matches multiple files as the destination to the `mv` command. What *single* file is `${i}_*_sites.txt` supposed to represent?

Comment: You just said the same thing that anubhava said. What's the point of that?

Comment: It's a comment that transcends any particular answer.

Comment: Anyway, that same -exact- comment was posted before you did. If it is not adding anything, then you should keep it to yourself. It is a website to help. Keep that in mind.

Comment: When I see a problem in the question itself, I don't scan the answers to see what discussion is going on there.

Comment: Well you should, otherwise its the same as a duplicated answer. Once again: it ADDS NOTHING to the post. Read the stack overflow documentation on how to answer. You might find it helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The `mv` command doesn't recognize the `*` wildcard; the shell does.

This:

```
foo*.txt
```

expands to a list of all files in the current directory whose names start with `foo` and end with `.txt`. If you pass `foo*.txt` as an argument to `mv`, the `mv` command never sees the `*`; it only sees the list of files.

Which means that if you have files `foo1.txt` and `foo2.txt`, this:

```
mv foo*.txt bar*.txt
```

will *not* rename `foo1.txt` to `bar1.txt` and `foo2.txt` to `bar2.txt` -- because `bar*.txt` can only expand to a list of files *that already exist*. If there are no existing files matching `bar*.txt`, then the above expands to:

```
mv foo1.txt foo2.txt bar42.txt
```

which is an error unless `bar42.txt` happens to be a directory. It will expand in various other ways depending on what files happen to exist at the moment -- and none of them are likely to be what you want.

If there are no file matching a given wildcard, the behavior depends on the shell and your current settings. In `bash`, with default settings, the wildcard just isn't expanded -- which is probably why you're getting a file with a `*` in its name.

There are bulk rename tools that will do what you want (I haven't used them myself).

Another approach I often use is to list the files to a text file, edit the file manually, and then run it as a script. For example, I might do this:

```
ls foo*.txt > tmp
```

then manually edit `tmp` to turn each line into a command that does what I want:

```
foo1.txt
foo2.txt
```

-->

```
mv foo1.txt bar1.txt
mv foo2.txt bar2.txt
```

and then run the command:

```
. ./tmp
```

Comment: I'm really late to the party, but what if the files do exist? I.e. I've just edited a whole bunch of files using a script, but stored the edited files in `tmp/*.json`. Now I would like to move the edited files from `tmp/*.json` to `release/*.json`. I know that all the files in `tmp/` exist with the same names in `release/`, can I trust that `mv tmp/*.json release/*.json` will overwrite the correct file with the correct contents? For now I'll just use python with `os.listdir()` and `sh.move()`, but for another time it would be nice to know :)

Comment: @VegardGjeldvikJervell The `mv` command takes a single argument as the target: `mv file1 file2 file3 ... target`, If the target is a directory, the files are moved into that directory. If it's a file, there can be only one source file, and it's renamed or moved, with the clobbered if it exists and you have permission. `mv tmp/*.json release/*.json` won't work. `mv tmp/*.json release/.` probably will. (I append the `/.` to make it clear that I'm referring to a directory; the `.` probably isn't necessary.)

Comment: If you type `mv tmp/*.json release/*.json`, both wildcard will expand, and the last file in the list that `release/*.json` expands to will be taken as the target. (`mv` has no idea that it's the result of a wildcard expansion.) If each wildcard expands to a single file, it may work. If they expand to multiple files, you'll probably get an error message -- unless the last thing that `release/*.json` expands to happens to be the name of an existing directory.

Comment: Thank you! It makes complete sense when you spell it out for me :)

Answer (score 7):

Problem is quoting. Glob pattern should be outside quote so you need:

```
"${i}_"*"_sites.txt"
```

Comment: I didn't work, I got this awful message: usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: If `"${i}_"*"_sites.txt"` pattern is matching more than 1 files then mv will will fail since destination can only be a single file/directory.

Comment: But I thought that the `*` will make it match different files. Isn't that what this wildcard is doing? Going through all the different files that match the pattern `"${i}_"*"_sites.txt"`

Comment: What Can I do to make the different files that match `"${i}_"*"_sites.txt"` be saved?

Comment: See `"${i}_"*"_sites.txt"` is not a source but destination file for `mv`

Comment: `"${i}_"*"_sites.txt"` will match any **existing files** that already exist.

Comment: So, if I redirect this to another folder will this work?

Comment: Yes if you give a folder name in destination if mv command it should work.