# Issue in mv command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im trying to run mv command using shell script but it gives me

```
mv: cannot stat `/opt/logs/merchantportal/logger.log.20160501.*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `/opt/logs/merchantapi/logger.log.20160501.*': No such file or directory
```

// THIS IS MY SHELL SCRIPT

```
#!/bin/bash
now="$(date +'%Y%m%d')"
merchantPortalLogsPath="/opt/logs/merchantportal"
merchantApiLogsPath="/opt/logs/merchantapi"
currentDate="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
olderDate="$(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "1 days ago")"
merchantPortalLogsPathBackup=$merchantPortalLogsPath"."$olderDate
merchantApiLogsPathBackup=$merchantApiLogsPath"."$olderDate

mkdir $merchantPortalLogsPathBackup
mkdir $merchantApiLogsPathBackup
echo $merchantPortalLogsPath"/logger.log."$olderDate".*" $merchantPortalLogsPathBackup"/"
echo $merchantApiLogsPath"/logger.log."$olderDate".*" $merchantApiLogsPathBackup"/"

mv $merchantPortalLogsPath"/logger.log."$olderDate".*" $merchantPortalLogsPathBackup"/"
mv $merchantApiLogsPath"/logger.log."$olderDate".*" $merchantApiLogsPathBackup"/"
```

// BUT DIRECTORY IS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY

[image]

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074999/using-mv-command-wont-recognize-as-wildcard Very good write-up of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
".*"
```

Putting the `*` inside double quotes will prevent the shell from treating that as a wildcard and will instead take it as a literal `*` character. Instead, change your script so that it does not double quote the `*`. For example:

```
mv ${merchantPortalLogsPath}/logger.log.${olderDate}.* ${merchantPortalLogsPathBackup}/
mv ${merchantApiLogsPath}/logger.log.${olderDate}.* ${merchantApiLogsPathBackup}/
```

Note: Technically should actually double quote the variable expansions to handle paths with spaces and other special characters in them. But I have not shown that to focus just on the problem at hand.

Answer (score -2):

The log directories exist, but the log files *within* those directories did not.  Since `mv` cannot move from data a log file that doesn't first exist, it complains, rather vaguely:

> No such file or directory

---

Note:  IMHO vague error messages are documentation/interface bugs -- if the error had said only:

> No such file

And not left the user wondering if there was a missing *directory* it would have seemed less puzzling, since that message would clearly imply that the *directory* where the file was supposed to exist did in fact exist.

But consider this egregious *GNU* `mv` example, where a directory `/tmp/a/` does not exist:

```
mv /tmp/a/b/c/d /tmp/foo
```

Output to STDERR:

```
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/a/b/c/d': No such file or directory
```

Now, the directory `/tmp/a/` doesn't exist, and also the directories `/tmp/b/` and `/tmp/a/b/c/`, and the file `/tmp/a/b/c/d`, none of them exist.  The user is given no indication of *which* of those is the problem, and it's even possible (unusual, but possible) that `/tmp/` doesn't exist.  Where as writing just a few lines of code could output an error message that said something so much more useful, like:

```
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/a/b/c/d': `/tmp/` exists, but not directory `/tmp/a/`
```

...which collectively would probably save years of user-time.